# R - Reset options after autoprinting

Tags: r

As Martin pointed out [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/1997-August/017475.html),
on.exit() happens after the function is complete but before auto-printing:

```
tst2 <- function(x = pi, dig = 3) {
  oo <- options(digits = dig)
  on.exit(options(oo))
  print(x)
  x
}

tst2()
[1] 3.14
[1] 3.14159
```

But if I do want my result being autoprinted with 3 digits and do NOT want to change options("digits") persistantly, how then am I supposed to reset options("digits") after auto-printing has been done?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the best way to go?

```
> tst2 <- function(x = pi) {
+   class(x) <- c("tdi", class(x))
+   return(x)
+ }


> print.tdi <- function(x, digits=3, ...){
+   opt <- options(digits=digits)
+   on.exit(options(opt))
+   class(x) <- class(x)[class(x)!="tdi"]
+   NextMethod()
+ }


> getOption("digits")
[1] 7

> # no print required
> x <- tst2()

> # ..ok. Print with default digits:
> tst2()
[1] 3.14

> # if want other number of digits, use print
> print(tst2(), digits=7)
[1] 3.141593

> # global digits are not touched
> getOption("digits")
[1] 7
```

But still missing the possibility to define digits for auto-printing without changing global options right in the main function ...